# PHP "подвисает" при запуске

Tags: php, macos

На локалхосте нормально крутятся сайты на PHP+Apache, работает все быстро, но в консоли, с недавних пор, PHP работает странно.

Вводим, например:

```
php -r "echo 'ok';"
```

Около 5 секунд ни чего не происходит, потом выводится «ok».
Такая проблема возникает абсолютно всегда, когда PHP запускается из консоли.

Конфиг: https://pastebin.com/7R1HnG4u

Мне подсказали, что проблема может быть в DNS, вот вывод `scutil --dns`:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : iidf.ru
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.4.4
  if_index : 4 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Not Reachable
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Not Reachable
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Not Reachable
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Not Reachable
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Not Reachable
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Not Reachable
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : iidf.ru
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.4.4
  if_index : 4 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: с дефолтным консольным конфигом попробуйте для начала

Comment: Ммм, а где взять дефолтный конфиг? Чуток погуглив я не нашел ни каких "консольных" конфигов.

Comment: для вэб сервера и для консоли традиционно юзаются отдельные конфиги `php.ini` и `php_cli.ini` соответственно. Так что если одно работает, а у другое проблемы, то начните с проверки конфига. Где взять - хз,  в дистрибутиве,  например. OSX я в глаза не видел по большому счету, но принцип думаю везде один.

Comment: А при чем DNS если в коде нет никаких обращений к Интернету? Если PHP долго отрабатывает то подключите профайлинг и проверьте список подключаемых расширений в консольном конфиге.

Comment: `php -i | grep ini`  - вернет путь к конфигу

Comment: Я приложил конфиг, путь которого был найден как раз таким способом

Comment: `php --ini` Есть ли еще какие файлы?

Comment: Нет, конфиг один.

Comment: Стандартно, cli не ограниченно по времени. Вы уверенны что это правельный ini?

Comment: Я уверен, что это ini, который используется php при работе в консоли.